# Is there someway to do just a simple string manipulation in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Is there someway to do just a simple string manipulation in Azure Data Factory?

Something as simple as I have a storage blob with a tab separated file, and I want to move it over into a storage table ... but make some

And I want to say, convert the tabs to commas, merge columns 4 through to the last column

Answer (score 4):

You could do this with a [Custom Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-use-custom-activities), but the thing to remember about Azure Data Factory is that it is mainly for orchestration (not transform).  That means it doesn't itself have a great deal of ability to do transform.

Another way to do this would be to use Azure Data Lake Analytics (ADLA), which would probably be my preference as I'm using it a lot at the moment.  If you don't already have an ADLA account though it might seem a bit of overhead.

I've taken a sample file and it converted it as per your requirements using U-SQL using this [sample file](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fcb41f5198f644c6895523f01bd1692a):

```
DECLARE @inputFilepath string = "input/input67.tsv";
DECLARE @outputFilepath string = "output/output67.csv";

@input =
    EXTRACT rowId int,
            col1 int,
            col2 int,
            col3 int,
            col4 int
    FROM @inputFilepath
    USING Extractors.Tsv(skipFirstNRows : 1);


// Concat the four columns
@output =
    SELECT rowId,
           string.Concat(col1.ToString(), col2.ToString(), col3.ToString(), col4.ToString()) AS col5
    FROM @input;


// Export as csv
OUTPUT @output
TO @outputFilepath
USING Outputters.Csv(quoting:false);
```